# In Bloxburg, what happens if you don't hit the correct buttons while cooking?

Tags: roblox

When cooking food in Bloxburg, occasionally little circles/bubbles appear with either a letter in them or a clicky-finger icon. If it's a letter, you have to hit that letter on your keyboard. If it's a clicky finger, you have to click on the little circle. (The actions are slightly different on a tablet or other touch-style interface, but the idea is the same.)

I've occasionally missed one or two bubbles, and nothing much happened - *maybe* cooking that item took a little longer than usual, but not noticeably so. What happens if you miss a whole bunch of them, though? Is there a threshold of incorrectness beyond which Bad Things Happen? Or does the game just figure that you've abandoned cooking that item, so all you lose is the price of the ingredients?

(Leveling up my cooking skill already takes forever, hence not being willing to just try it out - what if it makes my cooking skill go down?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, you complete it more slowly. I didn't take any XP penalty from missing - in fact, I actually levelled up from doing so, and continued gaining XP. I could not tell you whether that applies equally to high levels but I see no reason why it shouldn't.